# Categorical predictors where response is 0/1 [decision trees]

Tags: cart

In section 9.2.4 of Elements of Statistical Learning (pasted below for reference), it states that if the response variable is binary, then predictor classes can be ordered according to proportion falling in outcome class 1.

What does this mean? Is it saying that rather than splitting this categorical variable based on its categories, we split it based on the outcome of the class?

For example, consider a predictor $X_1$ the following values [cat, dog, bird, whale, dolphin, fish] and the response is [1, 0], where 1 represents mammal and 0 represents not mammal.

When we use $X_1$ to perform a split at a node, we split based on whether the examples are mammal and not mammal rather than, say, whether the example is a cat or not a cat, a dog or not a dog, etc...? I don't think this is what it's saying because that would be weird, but it sounds like it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you create an encoded variable whose values are based on the proportion of the binary classes instead of iterating over all possible combinations of the classes to find the best split. For example, in the following table:
[image]

A would be encoded as 1, B would be encoded as 2, C would be encoded as 3. This is much less expensive than determining how to break up A, B, and C into 2 groups.

Comment: Is A,B,C the categorical variables?

Comment: The A, B, and C are classes of the 'Predictor' categorical variable. They could be [dog, cat, bird, ...] like in your example.

Comment: Oh. So when you perform the split with this now encoded variable, do you essentially perform the split by checking $X_i <= 2$? Rather than checking if $X_i =$ DOG or $X_i =$ NOT DOG?

Comment: In the original variable, the tree would check every possible combination of A, B, and C. This requires 2^(3-1)-1 = 3 calculations. This grows quickly as you get more classes. If you had A, B, C, D, E, F, G, you would need to check 2^(7-1)-1=63 different potential groupings: {{A,B},{C,D,E,F,G}} , {{A,B,G},{C,D,E,F,}}, etc. However, when you encode the classes as ordered, you only need to check 6 potential splits.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of encoding?

Comment: In modern tree based algorithm implementations, the algorithm will not search all possible combinations of an unordered variable anyway. Most implementations require all predictors to be numeric, and if they are not, they will encode the categorical variables internally as either ordered or dummy variables. In this case, the disadvantage to encoding is that you lose the flexibility to group any classes together since they are now ordered and must be split according to their order.

Comment: Ah I see, so practically speaking, there aren't really any disadvantages to ecoding?